# using from_string with boost date

Tags: c++, string, locale, boost-date-time

I have the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>


#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/parsers.hpp>

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>

using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 std::string ds("2011-01-02");
date dt(from_string(ds));
date_facet *f=new date_facet("%Y-%m-%d");

 std::locale loc=std::locale(std::locale::classic(),f);
std::cout.imbue(loc);


   std::cout<<dt<<std::endl;


  return 0;

}
```

and when I compile it, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccBWTFcx.o: In function `unsigned short boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<boost::gregorian::greg_month>(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
   b.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9date_time19month_str_to_ushortINS_9gregorian10greg_monthEEEtRKSs[unsigned short boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<boost::gregorian::greg_month>(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)]+0x97): undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptr()'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

is this a library link issue?

Comment: Yes, it is a library link issue. Have you linked against the boost static libs?

Comment: nope, I hadn't, I just did and am getting the error I have listed below....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost date_time isn't header only, you need to link it on the command line, for example:

```
gcc myprogram.cpp -omyprogram -lboost_date_time
```

Comment: thanks Autopulated, I did that, now I get this error: error: ‘locale’ was not declared in this scope
how do I fix that?

Comment: no, I just compiled it again...does it work when you compile?

Comment: And it's from the same code that you posted?? not declared errors are from the compiler, which runs before the linker, so you wouldn't have got to the linking stage if there was a compiler error -- unless it's from a different file, maybe?

Comment: you're right.....I need to go get myself a drink...I ran the wrong file....sorry. thanks it worked